# How do I create a view of a picture library that does NOT display thumbnails? SP 2016 On-prem

Tags: 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, picture-library

In the Images library of the site collection, I have a large number of images. I'd like to create view which displays specific columns in a list view **without** any thumbnails.

When I create a new view, choosing "standard view" gives me a huge list of columns pre-checked which I cannot un-check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the *Style* in your view ,
Navigate to your library, click on the `library ribbon tab` and click on `Modify View`

[image]

Scroll down to `Style` and change the default(thumbnail) style and choose other style 
[image]